# Using R to subset overlapping daily sensor data

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set (3.2 million rows) in R which consists of pairs of time (milliseconds) and volts. The sensor that gathers the data only runs during the day so the time is actually the milliseconds since start-up that day.

For example, if the sensor runs 12 hours per day, then the maximum possible time value for one day is 43,200,000 ms (`12h * 60m * 60s * 1000ms`).

The data is continually added to a single file, which means there are many overlapping time values:

```
X: [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5...] // example if range was 1-5 for one day
Y: [voltage readings at each point in time...]
```

I would like to separate each "run" into unique data frames so that I could clearly see individual days. Currently when I plot the entire data set it is incredibly muddy because in fact all of the days are being shown in the single plot. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm quite confused as to why this is attracting downvotes and close votes. It is clear and an example is provided. It's not blindingly obvious to solve either.

Comment: I was confused too. I thought I was giving a basic example in hopes that a solution to the basic example would enable me to tailor a solution for the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data.frame `df` has columns `X` and `Y`, you can use `diff` to find every time `X` goes down (meaning a new day, it sounds like):

```
df$Day = cumsum(c(1, diff(df$X) < 0))
Day1 = df[df$Day==1,]
plot(Day1$X, Day1$Y)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Now I just wrap it in a function and I can get any day I want.